# How do I change the sound of the Instrument Sytrus / preset "Angelic whistle" so it doesnt deafen you?

Tags: fl-studio

I have a song and I want to use a whistle for a secondary melody it has. I chose the instrument Instrument Synth Classic / Sytrus / preset "Angelic whistle". The problem is the sound is too sharp I guess, and it deafens you when you listen it. I've heard songs where they used whistles and they werent annoying at all. How can I set that instrument in FL Studio so it doesnt deafen you when you listen it?

Comment: Set the mixer level

Comment: You can also use a channel EQ to reduce the high frequencies.

Comment: Try monitoring your whole mix at a lower volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Angelic whistle" preset is simply a sine wave with unison, vibrato, and reverb.  EQ will not do anything useful.  Turn the volume down.  Consult the [FL Studio manual](https://www.image-line.com/fl-studio-learning/fl-studio-online-manual/) if you are not familiar with the volume controls.

Comment: I did that, I turned the volume down for that sound, it seems to be ok